# Equation for non-cyclic sequence based around pascal's triangle

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

This question is an extension of [Need help in determining where this pascal's triangle-like sequence comes from.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155289/need-help-in-determining-where-this-pascals-triangle-like-sequence-comes-from)

---

To summarise, a binary sequence of length `n` can have `2^n` possible values which the initial question grouped as being the number of cycles (c) and the number of ones (k) when the number is wrapped around itself

Eg. The sequence `0011011` has `n=7`, `c=2` and `k=4`, so does `1001101` and `1100110`

So the equation for the number of elements following this pattern can be given as:

$$
\begin{align}
f(n,k,c) & = f_{00}(n,k,c)+2f_{01}(n,k,c)+f_{11}(n,k,c) \\
& = \binom{n-k}{c}\binom{k-1}{c-1}\left[1+\frac{k}{n-k}\right]
\end{align}
$$

---

I wish to determine the equation for a non-wrapped version for the distribution based on the number of ones `(k)` the number of 0->1 transitions `(c0)` and the number of 1->0 transitions `(c1)`. Listing then summing all the permutations are(code in clojure):

```
(defn num-to-arr [m x]
  (cond (= 0 m) []

        :else
        (let [arr (vec (repeat m 0))]
          (reduce (fn [out i]
                    (assoc out i (bit-and 1 (bit-shift-right x (- m (inc i))))))
                  arr
                  (range m)))))

(defn measure [xs]
  (loop [x    (first xs)
         acc  [x 0 0]
         xs   (next xs)]
    (cond (empty? xs)
          acc

          :else
          (let [x-n (first xs)
                i   (+ x (bit-shift-left x-n 1))
                acc-n (if (zero? x-n)
                        acc
                        (update-in acc [0] inc))
                acc-n (if (#{1 2} i) 
                         (update-in acc-n [i] inc)
                         acc-n)]
            (recur x-n acc-n (next xs))))))

(defn dist [m]
  (for [i (range (bigint (Math/pow 2 m)))]
    (let [arr (common/num-to-arr m i)]
      (measure arr))))
```

and the results for n=7 are:

```
(sort (frequencies (dist 7)))

[[k, c0, c1]  f(n, k, c0, c1)]

([[0 0 0] 1]
 [[1 0 1] 1]
 [[1 1 0] 1]
 [[1 1 1] 5]
 [[2 0 1] 1]
 [[2 1 0] 1]
 [[2 1 1] 5]
 [[2 1 2] 4]
 [[2 2 1] 4]
 [[2 2 2] 6]
 [[3 0 1] 1]
 [[3 1 0] 1]
 [[3 1 1] 5]
 [[3 1 2] 6]
 [[3 2 1] 6]
 [[3 2 2] 9]
 [[3 2 3] 3]
 [[3 3 2] 3]
 [[3 3 3] 1]
 [[4 0 1] 1]
 [[4 1 0] 1]
 [[4 1 1] 5]
 [[4 1 2] 6]
 [[4 2 1] 6]
 [[4 2 2] 9]
 [[4 2 3] 3]
 [[4 3 2] 3]
 [[4 3 3] 1]
 [[5 0 1] 1]
 [[5 1 0] 1]
 [[5 1 1] 5]
 [[5 1 2] 4]
 [[5 2 1] 4]
 [[5 2 2] 6]
 [[6 0 1] 1]
 [[6 1 0] 1]
 [[6 1 1] 5]
 [[7 0 0] 1])
```

---

Can this be expressed as an equation?

Comment: @qiaochu-yuan: can you take a look?

Comment: @zander: can you take a look?